# How to block an insert into a table if a reference between 2 other tables exist?

Tags: sql, sqlite

completely newb on DBs here... Trying to make simple program to help an orphanage around my area. The question: Suppose I have table A and table B referencing table C through a foreign key constraint. Is there a way to block an insertion in table A referencing an element X in the table C if there is an element Y in table B already referencing X?

Table A: empty
Table B: Y(references X)
Table C: X

Attempt to insert Z(references X) in table A

Table A: Z(references X) <<--- Blocked
Table B: Y(references X)
Table C: X

Sorry for the newb question, my first try with a DB... And although I have done some research, I don't even know the proper terms to put on the search bars to look for this situation.

Comment: embedded sqlite

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I think you need get to know a bit of theory here. Like dependencies, referential integrity etc.

Comment: Yes @bonCodigo , I've been reading stuff lately. I read about it, and found that this problem (dealing with exclusive subtypes) is recurrent, with no 'accepted universal answer' for this. I'm probably struggling more than the usual developer though, as I'm not used to db development. It seems now that my issue is trying to put every 'db-to-reality-representation' consistency check inside sql, giving no responsabilities to the application layer using that... It's another war: where should business logic go... Although I would love to see every rule in sql, guess it's not the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

i might be wrong, but to me it looks like you are trying to solve the wrong problem ...

it sounds like tables A and B are some sort of subtype related to each other like student and teacher ... both are persons

i'll stick to the student - teacher example here, but it's all the same for other entities that can be treated alike

so depending on the relationships you want to have, the status of a person, either being a student or teacher can either be a discriminator field in the person table telling you what subtype a person is, or it can be part of another concrete relationship, for example if you have the case that a person can be a student in one case and at the same time a teacher in another... (the discriminator field would move to the table that describes the relationship so you get one discriminator per concrete relation)

in your abstract world with A, B and C it could look like this:

A
[A1]
[A2]

B
[B1]
[B2]

C
[C1]

R
[R1;C1;A1;NULL;A]

while the columns for R are:
PK
C reference
A reference
B reference
discriminator

and a constraint for R restricting the column C ref to be unique

the unique is the thing that prevents the unwanted additional reference you described and will block an insert to R (not exactly what you wanted, since you can still have an entry in A ... but it will prevent the additional reference to the C entity that was already referenced, which will most likely be enough)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, This is indeed a subtype problem... But your proposed solution would allow the insertion of a [R1;C1,A1,B1,A] entry in R, and that is inconsistent... After some research, I guess that the problem I am facing is that I'm trying to put all the business logic and consistency maintenance inside the SQL... And that would probably need lots of triggers, stored procedures and functions... Although this is not simple to do in pure SQL, most of those stuff are easier to implement in the application using the DB, specially if the DB will not be used by any other aplications...

Comment: @Mateus ... depending on your DBMS this can be done in a quite simple fashion ... you can either have a trigger that is setting all but one of R's reference columns NULL on insert/update, or have something like TSQL's CHECK constraint testing if only the right reference column is filled